# Adding Li's to Ol's

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code

```
$('<ol />').appendTo('#one');
$('<li />').append(a).appendTo('#one ol');
```

How can I combine into a single line of code? I tried this but in vain

```
$('<li />').append(a).appendTo('<ol />').appendTo('#one');
```

Comment: And yes, whatever you have written is right! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in a single line try this:

```
$('<ol />').appendTo('#one').append($('<li />').append(a));
```

The chaining is dependant on what element is returned from the previous function, in your original you were appending the `a` to the `li`, then the `li` to the `ol`, the the `li` to `#one`.

Comment: Awesome. Is there any difference in performance if I use your code instead of the one I used earlier?

Comment: I just tried your code and it creates multiple <ols>. That's not what I want. I want multiple li's added to a single <ol>

Comment: It should only create one `ol`, unless it's in a loop?

Comment: yes sorry it's in a loop. How do I change your code to cater to a loop

Comment: In that case you need two statements, one to create the `ol` outside the loop, and one to create the `li` element inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got your answer:

```
$("<ol />").append($('<li />').append(a)).appendTo('#one');
```

This does the trick!

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2suQ/1/

Comment: I think his question is "How can I combine into a single line of code?"

Comment: The question was how to combine these 2 lines into a single one, he already knows they work as they are now.

Comment: I just tried your code and it creates multiple <ols>. That's not what I want. I want multiple li's added to a single <ol>